# Django Change queryset with a function

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset

I have a queryset

```
class FlowQuerySets(models.QuerySet):
def top_ip_in(self):
    return self.values('ip_dst', 'ip_proto')\
            .annotate(traffic=Sum('bytes')).order_by('-traffic')[:10]
```

I need to reuse it 3 times but with a slight changes, by adding filter:

```
return self.values('ip_dst', 'ip_proto')\
           .filter(stamp_updated__lt=half_hour)\
           .annotate(traffic=Sum('bytes')).order_by('-traffic')[:10]
```

How do I implement this? Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could do it:

```
class FlowQuerySets(models.QuerySet):
    def top_ip_in(self, with_filter=False):
        queryset = self.values('ip_dst', 'ip_proto')
        if with_filter:
            queryset = queryset.filter(stamp_updated__lt=half_hour)
        queryset = queryset.annotate(traffic=Sum('bytes')).order_by('-traffic')[:10]
        return queryset
```

You can then invoke `top_ip_in()` if you don't need to filter or `top_ip_in(True)` otherwise.

[Querysets are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy), so the database won't be hit multiple times although `queryset` is modified several times.

Comment: Thanks! It was helpful